# pgadmin III backup screen freeze

Tags: backup, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

I wanted to get a backup for a very large database with pgAdmin, I started as usual backups, but after a couple of hours it still runs, and I can't cancel it also.

I don't even get to see the file being created.

so a couple of questions:
1. for big databases (more than 8GB) should we use command line only ? 
2. if I stop the pgAdmin process would be any side effect on the operational DB ?

BR